# wcf : string element nillable="false"

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a client that is mandating that my `required` string elements have `nillable="false"`, currently all strings in the wsdl come out will `nillable="true"`, IE:

```
<xs:element name="username" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
```

How can i change the `nillable="false"` ?!?  I will take any suggestions on how to do this?  Am I the first person that has run into this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039850/wcf-wsdl-nillable-attributes/21266714#21266714.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this element defined in your data contract?

If it's not already done, try adding a `IsRequired=true` clause to the data member attribute:

```
[DataContract]
class YourDataStructure
{
   ......

   [DataMember(IsRequired=True)]
   string username;

   .....
}
```

Other than that, I'm not aware of any way to influence the XSD being rendered from your WCF data contract, short of writing your own WsdlExporter extension (which is totally possible - just seems a bit overkill here).

Comment: Hi Marc.  Thanks for the suggestion. 
I have tried the IsRequired=True, that only removes the minOccurs="0".

Comment: @Steven: I was afraid of that :-(

Comment: Hi Marc, 
Good news, I already had the WsdlExporter in my wcf service for flattening out the wsdl, so it was actually quite easy to implement this in the WsdlExporter extension.  
Thanks for the suggestion, without it I don't think I would have gone down that avenue.  
(Note: I used http://blogs.msdn.com/stan_kitsis/archive/2005/08/06/448572.aspx for Walking the XmlSchema, and when the appropriate element was found, I was able to go el.IsNillable=false; and it worked.
Thanks again. 
Steven

Comment: @stevenrosscampbellless, could you share your WSDLExporter solution with me please? I'm facing a similar issue. I don't have WSDLExporter and I'm currently looking at my possible solutions. I have a number of examples but none dealing with `nillable`s.

Comment: This doesn't make the schema element non-nillable - consumers like BCS (SharePoint) will still not understand this schema as having "non-null" values. I *know* this is an *old* answer, but this exact same answer has been asserted in multiple places and it *doesn't* address the fundamental problem with the WCF XSD generation.

Comment: See this answer for a sample WsdlExportExtension that sets nillable to false: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602749/setting-nillable-false-with-wcf/23366064#23366064