# WCF WSDL + Nillable Attributes

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service with a [Flattened WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801128/flat-wsdl-for-wcf-4-service/8057456#8057456), and the consumer at the other end is telling me the nillable="true" attributes are hosing them up. I tried setting EmitDefaultValue = false in my service contract, but I didn't notice any change in behavior.

Admittedly, I have never had to dig into WSDL generation at this level before so I'm a little lost. Perhaps there a tweak to be made in the bit of code posted below that may solve my problem? If I'm at least in the correct place, I'll keep investigating.

Is there a simple way to remove the nillable="true" attributes from my WSDL, and is that going to have unintended consequences? Thanks!

```
public class FlatWsdl : IWsdlExportExtension, IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = exporter.GeneratedXmlSchemas;

        foreach (ServiceDescription wsdl in exporter.GeneratedWsdlDocuments)
        {
            List<XmlSchema> importsList = new List<XmlSchema>();

            foreach (XmlSchema schema in wsdl.Types.Schemas)
            {
                AddImportedSchemas(schema, schemaSet, importsList);
            }

            wsdl.Types.Schemas.Clear();

            foreach (XmlSchema schema in importsList)
            {
                RemoveXsdImports(schema);
                wsdl.Types.Schemas.Add(schema);
            }
        }
    }

    ...omitted the rest of FlatWsdl.cs for brevity...
}
```

Comment: You have to write your own WsdlExportExtension.
See this answer for a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602749/setting-nillable-false-with-wcf/23366064#23366064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct simple way to achieve this. You'll have to use [WsdlExporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlexporter.aspx) to implement it yourself. Whether it will have unintended consequences depends on your intentions :-)

EDIT:

Have a look at the MSDN example of [IWSDLExportExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx). It will allow you to do exactly what you want. Admittedly, it's a bit of a hassle to get it right, but you're looking in the right direction.

Comment: I chose to take no action in the end, but if I were to attempt to remove the nillable attributes I would use WsdlExporter in the ExportEndpoint method.

Comment: Is there some change to this behavior in .Net 4.5? I'm about to face the same situation now. Don't have IWSDLExportExtension in project.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the internet for ours, me and my team decided to go with a different approach to get rid of the nillable="true". What we did was the following:

1. Registered a special `HttpModule` during application startup.
2. This module registered a handler to the BeginRequest event.
3. In the case the WSDL or XSD are requested (checked by looking at the query string) the hooked handler would replace the default `Response.Filter` with a decorator (a Stream).
4. This decorator would buffer the written data until the end of the document was reached.
5. When all data is written the decorator builds up an `XDocument` based on that data and goes through that document to set (among other things, such as adding documentation) nillable="false".

This works all quite lovely.

The idea of using `Response.Filter` was found [here](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters).

Here's the HttpModule:

```
public class WsdlInterceptionHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var context = application.Context;

            if (IsRequestForWsdl(context.Request))
            {
                context.Response.Filter = 
                    new WsdlAnnotationsFilterDecorator(context.Response.Filter);
            }
        };
    }

    private static bool IsRequestForWsdl(HttpRequest request) { ... }
}
```

Here's the `WsdlAnnotationsFilterDecorator`:

```
public class WsdlAnnotationsFilterDecorator : Stream
{
    private const string DefinitionsEndOfFileMarker = "</wsdl:definitions>";
    private const string SchemaEndOfFileMarker = "</xs:schema>";

    private readonly Stream inputStream;
    private readonly StringBuilder responseXml = new StringBuilder();
    private bool firstWrite = true;
    private string endOfFileMarker = DefinitionsEndOfFileMarker;

    public WsdlAnnotationsFilterDecorator(Stream inputStream)
    {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.responseXml = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanSeek { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
    public override long Length { get { return 0; } }
    public override long Position { get; set; }

    public override void Close()
    {
        inputStream.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        inputStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return inputStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long length)
    {
        inputStream.SetLength(length);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return inputStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        string valueToWrite = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);

        SetEndOfFileMarker(valueToWrite);

        if (!valueToWrite.EndsWith(this.endOfFileMarker))
        {
            responseXml.Append(valueToWrite);
        }
        else
        {
            responseXml.Append(valueToWrite);

            string finalXml = responseXml.ToString();

            finalXml = WsdlAnnotator.Annotate(finalXml);

            byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(finalXml);

            inputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }

    private void SetEndOfFileMarker(string valueToWrite)
    {
        if (firstWrite)
        {
            int definitionTagIndex = valueToWrite.IndexOf("<wsdl:definitions");
            int schemaTagIndex = valueToWrite.IndexOf("<xs:schema");

            if (definitionTagIndex > -1 || schemaTagIndex > -1)
            {
                firstWrite = false;

                if (definitionTagIndex > -1 && schemaTagIndex > -1)
                {
                    endOfFileMarker =
                        definitionTagIndex < schemaTagIndex 
                            ? DefinitionsEndOfFileMarker : SchemaEndOfFileMarker;
                }
                else if (definitionTagIndex > -1)
                {
                    endOfFileMarker = DefinitionsEndOfFileMarker;
                }
                else if (schemaTagIndex > -1)
                {
                    endOfFileMarker = SchemaEndOfFileMarker;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `WsdlAnnotator` is where all the magic happens:

```
internal static class WsdlAnnotator
{
    internal static string Annotate(string xml)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        try
        {
            // Your magic here.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                ex.Message + " Document: " + document.ToString(), ex);
        }

        return document.ToString(SaveOptions.None);
    }
```