# wcf how to set not nullable DataMember for SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm implementing a wcf Service.
My class is structured like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class NotificationsSapInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)] 
    public string ID_CLIENT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string ID_OBJECT_CODE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string ID_TYPE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string ID_SUB_TYPE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string ID_DIVISION { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ID_LINE { get; set; }
}
```

The problem that occurs is that in the WSDL generated it seems ignoring the `Required` and the `StringLength` Attributes.

This is the portion of WSDL generated.

```
<xs:complexType name="NotificationsSapInfo">

<xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="ID_CLIENT" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

<xs:element name="ID_DIVISION" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

<xs:element name="ID_LINE" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

<xs:element name="ID_OBJECT_CODE" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

<xs:element name="ID_SUB_TYPE" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

<xs:element name="ID_TYPE" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will work in you case but I use it for data contracts and data validation:

On your DataMember attribute try adding: IsRequired = true

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
```

Comment: I've already used this parameter, but unfortunately it does not work.. :(

Comment: @Galma88 the only other option is to use an extension as referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602749/setting-nillable-false-with-wcf/23366064#23366064